# Evaluate Equation from String

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, equation

I have a String stored in a table with two logic gates which looks like `1*((CUBL>1)*((DIFL>1)*1))`.

I have been able to replace the text with values from a different table i.e. `1*((1500>1)*((0>1)*1))`. The issue i am having is being able to evaluate the equations between the brackets. The following is a list of steps that i believe are needed.

```
1*((CUBL>1)*((DIFL>1)*1)) -> 1*((1500>1)*((0>1)*1))
1*((1500>1)*((0>1)*1)) -> 1*(1*(0*1))
1*(1*(0*1)) -> 1*(1*0)
1*(1*0) -> 1*0 = 0
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for an expression parser, rather than a database.  Must you do this in SQL Server?

Comment: It would make things easier. We are currently doing this within vb but it would be beneficial to do it all within tsql.

Comment: I'm thinking you're going to want to do this in a proc then.

Comment: That was my thinking or within a function.